# How to test an async function and patch a class called within

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio, python-unittest, pytest-asyncio

I have the following directory structure:

```
├── project
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── __init__.py.py
│   │   ├── module.py
│   ├── main.py
├── tests
│   ├── test_main.py
```

where `module.py` is:

```py
class My_Class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        raise Exception("This is a test exception")
```

and `main.py` is:

```py
import asyncio

from modules.module import My_Class

async def main():
    my_class = My_Class()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I am trying to write `test_main.py` such that `My_Class()` is patched so that the exception is not raised when running the test.

This is what I have now:

```py
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch

from project.main import main

@pytest.mark.asyncio
@patch("project.modules.module.My_Class")
async def test_main(mock_my_class):
    await main()
```

But I'm hitting this import error:

```
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Desktop\deleteme\tests\test_main.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests\test_main.py:4: in <module>
    from project.main import main
project\main.py:3: in <module>
    from modules.module import My_Class
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an empty `__int__.py` file to the directories you want to treat as modules. Here's a great SO answer for what that is and why it's needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/448279/190902

Comment: Thank you I forgot that in this example, but that doesn't solve the error that I'm getting. main.py ran successfully and properly imported the module without __init__.py as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to add the project directory to my path. As well, I had to modify the patch statement. Based on the mock documentation on "where to patch" [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch), the class needs to be patched where it is being used, so in my case that is `project.main.My_Class` not `project.modules.module.My_Class`.

```
import os
import sys

import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch

Parent_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
project_dir = os.path.join(Parent_dir, 'project')
sys.path.insert(0, project_dir)

from project.main import main

@pytest.mark.asyncio
@patch("project.main.My_Class")
async def test_main(mock_my_class):
    await main()
```